# accessing service from config map in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

i am trying to run an application in kubernetes with a backend and a frontend where the frontend knows about the backend host's address in a volume which is mounted from the contents of a configmap.
the app runs fine when i put the address of the backend deployment set on ingress but it is not practical and i want it to know about the backend by some kind of variable. I have also tried setting up the backend serice ip as an enviroment variable but it did not work.

i tried setting up an ingress and using the url to help the frontend access the backend host but i dont want to make the backend ip public for now, so this will not work.

my configMap is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: frontend-config
data:
  env.js: |
    window.env = {
      host: "http://backend.k8s.com"
    }
```

also here is my frontend deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cu-frontend
        image: **address to frontend image**
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/env.js
          subPath: env.js
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: frontend-config
```

and finally, this is my backend deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deployment
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cu-backend
        image: **address to backend image**
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly simple. If you don't want to expose your backend (which makes total sense), just create a `ClusterIP` service and put the name of the service as your `host` in your frontend application's configmap.

Comment: the backend service is already clusterIP. Do you by any chance mean something like this in the configMap?

`apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: frontend-config
data:
  env.js: |
    window.env = {
      host: backend-service:80
    }`

i have tried this and it did not work at all

Comment: do the pods belong to the same namespace? if they are in different namespaces, you need to put a full fqdn to the service, like this:
`host: http://backend-service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: both of the frontend and backend services and deployments belong to the same cluster.  this notation:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: frontend-config
data:
  env.js: |
    window.env = {
      host: http://backend-service
    }
`
nor this notation:
`apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: frontend-config
data:
  env.js: |
    window.env = {
      host: http://backend-service.default.svc.cluster.local
    }
`
works
i have been working on this problem for a long time now and some professional insight would be  great